# semiconductors-band theory

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

How conduction happens with the conduction band electrons?
I mean does the electrons which are responsible for the conduction of holes(by just moving from one atom to other) are those which are present in conduction band?
But it is also written that holes are generated in valence band (by movement of electrons from valence band to conduction band) than how holes can participate in conduction?
So i want to ask how conduction band electrons are used for conduction and valence band electrons cant be used where as valence band holes can used???
I am confused!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How holes conduct current?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/167602/)

Comment: If the valence band is full (all spots are taken up by electrons), it cannot conduct, because there is no place for additional electrons to move inside this band. This is why you need a hole in the valence band. Now once you this hole, you can imagine the underlying process in two ways: the electrons are hopping from into the hole and out of it. Or the hole itself is hopping around. It's really the same thing.